# Como eu executo um scrip só depois dele estar visível ao usuario?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tenho esse script:

```
var count = document.getElementById('contador').innerText;
var temp = count - 1000;
function counting() {
    if(temp<count) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('contador').innerText = temp;
            temp=temp+10;
            counting();
        }, 30);
    }else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('contador').innerText = count;
        }, 30);
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////

$(function(){
    let run = false
  let alturaContador = $('#contador').height()
    let distanciaContadorDoTopo = $('#contador').offset().top

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    let posicaoScroll = $(window).scrollTop()

    if (posicaoScroll >= (distanciaContadorDoTopo - (distanciaContadorDoTopo / 2)) && !run) {
    run = true
    alert('RODAR NÚMEROS')
      counting();
    }

  });
});
```

Que estou tentando fazer com que ele execute só depois que o usuario ver (Quando o usuario da scroll até o elemento) ele, porém sem sucesso, alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Exemplo: esse site > convergenciasjc.com.br tem esses números (+ DE 552000
HORAS) "rodando" porém o usr não vê porque eles carregam com site.

```
<ul id="certificado">                       

 <li class="conteudo_certificado">
    <span class="titulo_number">+ de</span><span id="contador" class="titulo_number count">950</span>
    <br>
    <span class="titulo_certificado">toneladas coletadas</span>
 </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Edita a pergunta e coloca tb o HTML/CSS de forma que a gente consiga simular o seu contexto. Vai ajudar a te responder, não precisa ser o html e css da página inteira, mas pelo menos desse pedaço de forma que de para testar

Comment: Seja mais claro, depois que "ele ver". Como você sabe que ele viu? ele executa alguma ação ao "ver" ?? Qual é objetivo de esperar ele ver? ele clica em algum botão sinalizando que ele viu?

Comment: *"só depois que o usuario ver ele"* ele quem? do jeito que escreveu para que o usuário tem q ver o script, e isso não acontece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute e veja se te ajuda

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      $('.scroll-aparecer').stop();
      if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
      // aqui ele vai executar o que você deseja, nesse caso mostrar uma tarja preta
         $('.scroll-aparecer').animate({
            height:"100px"
         }, 1000); /*Defina aqui o tempo em milisegundos */
      }else{
         $('.scroll-aparecer').animate({
         height:"0"
         }, 1000); /*Defina aqui o tempo em milisegundos */
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.geral-boxes{
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
}
.acao1,.acao2,.acao3{
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   height: 500px;
}
.acao1{
   background-color: #fff;
}
.acao2{
   background-color: #fff;
}.acao3{
   background-color: #fff;
}
.geral-boxes{
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
}

.scroll-aparecer{
   width: 50px;
   float: left;
   height: 0;
   background-color: #000;
   
   position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="acao1">AQUI ELE VIU E ROLOU PARA BAIXO</div>

<div class="acao2"></div>

<div class="acao3"></div>

<div class="scroll-aparecer"></div>
```

Comment: Meu deu mais direção, obrigado!